# How to use shopify liquid to extract from string?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I have the following string:

```
“Title
Content

Title
Content”
```

I want to extract each title and each content.

I have been trying to use Shopify remove operator but it’s getting really long and I’m not sure if there is a easier solution?

Comment: Hi! Would you provide Liquid source code?

Answer (score 0):

Using `split` filter *might* be the answer here!

However for this use case to work you need to add custom separators between each title/content block, if you do have access to the content, it would look something like this:

```html
<!-- Let's assume this content is coming from page.content -->
<h2>Title 1</h2><!-- inner-split --><p>content 1</p>
<!-- outer-split -->
<h2>Title 2</h2><!-- inner-split --><p>content 2</p>
```

```
<!-- this split the content into title/content blocks  -->
{% assign content_blocks = page.content | split: '<!-- outer-split -->' %}

<!-- Loop through all blocks to split then extract title/content -->
{% for block in content_blocks %}
  {% assign title_content = block | split: '<!-- inner-split -->' %}
  <!-- title -->
  {{ title_content[0] }}
  <!-- content -->
  {{ title_content[1] }}
{% endfor %}
```